# using the max-age request header

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

How do I configure my VLC to let Varnish respect the 'Cache-Control max-age' request header?

I noticed that by default varnish delivers cached content, even when I press F5 in my browser (Hence request a 'fresh' copy').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `vcl_hit` you can do the following:

```
if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ '\no-cache\b`) {
    purge;
    return (restart);
}
```

make sure you have imported the std vmod

```
import std;
```

Comment: The thing I don't like about this is that vcl_pass does not actually update the cache with the new entry. Would there be a way to return a fetch command instead?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the obj.age inside vcl_hit so no-cache is the best I can come up with.